# Read Nodes XML in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, feed

I'm new to this and I'm trying to collect all the data from an XML internet, so far everything works fine but can not find solution to catch the "fecha" attribute of the "dia" label and print it on a TextView . Can anyone help me? And another question, how I can print these values ​​in a textview?

```
<temperatura> 
<maxima> 14 </ maxima> 
<minima> 5 </ minima> 
<dato hora="06"> 6 </ dato > 
<dato hora="12"> 12 </ dato > 
<dato hora="18"> 13 </ dato > 
<dato hora="24"> 10 </ dato > 
</ temperatura>
```

XML:

```
<prediccion>
<dia fecha="2014-02-25">
<prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24"/>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12"/>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">15</prob_precipitacion>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="00-06"/>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="06-12">0</prob_precipitacion>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="12-18">5</prob_precipitacion>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="18-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
<cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24"/>
<cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"/>
<cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24"/>
<cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-06"/>
<cota_nieve_prov periodo="06-12"/>
<cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-18"/>
<cota_nieve_prov periodo="18-24"/>
<estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion=""/>
<estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion=""/>
<estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Muy nuboso">15</estado_cielo>
<estado_cielo periodo="00-06" descripcion=""/>
<estado_cielo periodo="06-12" descripcion="Poco nuboso">12</estado_cielo>
<estado_cielo periodo="12-18" descripcion="Muy nuboso">15</estado_cielo>
<estado_cielo periodo="18-24" descripcion="Cubierto">16n</estado_cielo>
<viento periodo="00-24">...</viento>
<viento periodo="00-12">...</viento>
<viento periodo="12-24">...</viento>
<viento periodo="00-06">...</viento>
<viento periodo="06-12">...</viento>
<viento periodo="12-18">
<direccion>SO</direccion>
<velocidad>10</velocidad>
</viento>
<viento periodo="18-24">...</viento>
<racha_max periodo="00-24"/>
<racha_max periodo="00-12"/>
<racha_max periodo="12-24"/>
<racha_max periodo="00-06"/>
<racha_max periodo="06-12"/>
<racha_max periodo="12-18"/>
<racha_max periodo="18-24"/>
<temperatura>
<maxima>14</maxima>
<minima>5</minima>
<dato hora="06">6</dato>
<dato hora="12">12</dato>
<dato hora="18">13</dato>
<dato hora="24">10</dato>
</temperatura>
<sens_termica>...</sens_termica>
<humedad_relativa>
<maxima>100</maxima>
<minima>65</minima>
<dato hora="06">95</dato>
<dato hora="12">65</dato>
<dato hora="18">75</dato>
<dato hora="24">100</dato>
</humedad_relativa>
<uv_max>3</uv_max>
</dia>
<dia fecha="2014-02-26">
...
</dia>
```

RSSReader.java

```
public class RSSReader {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    public Document getRSSFromServer(String url) {
        Document response = null;
        response = getDomFromXMLString(getFeedFromServer(url));
        return response;
    }

    private String getFeedFromServer(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        try {
            HttpGet httpget =new HttpGet(url);
            //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }

    private Document getDomFromXMLString(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public String getValue(Element item, String key) {
        NodeList nodeList = item.getElementsByTagName(key);
        return this.getElementValue(nodeList.item(0));
    }

    public final String getElementValue(Node node) {
        Node child;
        if (node != null) {
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = node.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                        .getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
String key_items = "dia"; //dia
String key_title = "prob_precipitacion"; //prob_precipitacion
String key_description = "estado_cielo"; //estado_cielo
String key_link = "viento"; //viento
String key_date = "temperatura"; //temperatura
//humedad_relativa ¿HORA?
String key_max = "maxima"; //max
String key_min = "minima"; //min
String key_hour = "hora"; //dato / Hora
String key_fecha = "fecha";
ListView lstPost = null;
List<HashMap<String, Object>> post_lists = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
RSSReader rssfeed = new RSSReader();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}


private class downloadWeather extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando tiempo actual...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        lstPost = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaaa);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.weather_item, R.id.TextView02, lists) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                // horaaemet // maxaemet // minaemet // fechaaemet // imgaemet // probabiaemet
                TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.probabiaemet);
                TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.horaaemet);
                TextView txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.maxaemet);
                TextView txt4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.minaemet);
                TextView txt5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fechaaemet);
                ImageView txt6 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgaemet);

                HashMap<String, Object> data = post_lists.get(position);
                txt1.setText(data.get(key_title).toString());
                txt3.setText(data.get(key_max).toString());
                txt4.setText(data.get(key_min).toString());
                //txt5.setText(data.get(key_fecha).toString());

                return view;
            }

        };
        Document xmlFeed = rssfeed.getRSSFromServer("http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_41065.xml"); //http://beta.studentitzone.com/rssfeed
        NodeList nodes = xmlFeed.getElementsByTagName("dia");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element item = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            HashMap<String, Object> feed = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            feed.put(key_title, rssfeed.getValue(item, key_title));
            feed.put(key_max, rssfeed.getValue(item, key_max)+"º");
            feed.put(key_min, rssfeed.getValue(item, key_min)+"º");
            post_lists.add(feed);
            lists.add(feed.get(key_title).toString());
        //Log.e("VALOR -> ", "attribute value = " + item.getAttribute( "fecha" ) );
                    //It's works. Show Attribute but, How I can put this result in a textview?
        }
        lstPost.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```